# How to code my javascript in order for toggle to work properly?

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I have javascript code to toggle hide and show information and works for one showMoreText section of text, but want 16 different toggle options for all the different links. Included is the image that works for the "Montana's Glacier" underneath Why is it Important? It does toggle, but I created another javascript page (toggle2.js) specifically for the "Ice now covers..." link, but it will not appear. [image]

**Code for first toggle option in toggle.js**

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = showMore;
}

function showMore(){
    var div = document.getElementById('showMoreText');
    var display = div.style.display;
    display == "none" ? div.style.display = "block" : div.style.display = "none";
}
```

**Code for second toggle option in toggle2.js**

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('toggle2').onclick = showMore;
}

function showMore(){
    var div = document.getElementById('showMoreText2');
    var display = div.style.display;
    display == "none" ? div.style.display = "block" : div.style.display = "none";
}
```

**Code within HTML for toggle1**

```
<div id="showMoreText" style="display: none"> (missing paranthesis)
```

**Code within HTML for toggle2**

```
<div id="showMoreText" style="display: none"> (missing paranthesis)
```

What is wrong? I want to be able to toggle to many different toggles (1-16) but when I click on toggle1, and want to click on toggle 2, it does not change. what variable is barring me from it work properly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Further Optimised based on Aleks G answer:

Your script:

```
window.onload = function(){
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++){      //here is set to 3
        document.getElementById('toggle'+i).onclick = function(i){
            return function(){
                showMore('showMoreText'+i);
            }
        }(i);
    }
}

function showMore(id){
    var div = document.getElementById(id),
        display = div.style.display;
    display == "none" ? div.style.display = "block" : div.style.display = "none";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="toggle1" class="toggle"></div>
<div id="toggle2" class="toggle"></div>
<div id="toggle3" class="toggle"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.toggle{
    display: none;
}
```

Actually, you don't even need the `id` in `div`. You can just loop through the class `toggle` and find all the `div`s.

Comment: Complete with closure. This is a complete answer.

Comment: Derek - Could you please explain the variables? Also, how would I label the different divs to correspond properly to this code? For example, the div name for extra information for toggle 1 would say "______" while toggle 2 div's name should say "_____"

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to have all toggles separately?  Why not just do this?

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = showMore1;
    document.getElementById('toggle2').onclick = showMore2;
    document.getElementById('toggle3').onclick = showMore3;
    ...
}

function showMore1() { showMore('showMoreText'); }
function showMore2() { showMore('showMoreText2'); }
function showMore3() { showMore('showMoreText3'); }
...

function showMore(id){
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    var display = div.style.display;
    display == "none" ? div.style.display = "block" : div.style.display = "none";
}
```

This is quite crude, feel free to optimise further.

Comment: To use this code, how would you go upon adding a code that you only see one visible "shoeMoreText" at a time? For example, I will click on toggle1 and then toggle 2, which will add the text for toggle right after toggle 1. What code to only show one toggle at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but just to go with the above, the window.onload function can be simplified into a single object, and the code recylcled.

```
window.onload = function() {
 var tList={'toggle1': 'showMore1','toggle2': 'showMore2','toggle3': 'showMore3'};
 for(var i in tList){document.getElementById(i).onclick = tList[i]};
}
```